# I want my stored procedure to only populate one instance of a name

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

I'm creating a stored procedure that populates two tables `tblAirport` and `tblCountry`. `tblCountry` gets its country names from `tblAirport` but I only want one instance of the country name to show up in `tblCountry. So far for my stored procedure I have this

```
DECLARE @PK INT = (SELECT PK FROM tblAirport WHERE strName = @strName)

IF @PK IS NULL
INSERT INTO tblAirport (ICAOCode,IATACode,strName,strCity,strCountry,degLat,minLat,secLat,Equator,degLong,minLong,secLong,Meridian,strElevation)
VALUES (@ICAOCode,@IATACode,@strName,@strCity,@strCountry,@degLat,@minLat,@secLat,@Equator,@degLong,@minLong,@secLong,@Meridian,@strElevation)
SET @PK = (SELECT PK FROM tblAirport WHERE strName = @strName);


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblCountry WHERE strCountry = @strCountry)
SET @strCountry = @strCountry + 'x'


INSERT INTO tblCountry (strCountry)
VALUES (@strCountry)
```

I tried using `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblCountry WHERE strCountry = @strCountry)
SET @strCountry = @strCountry + 'x'` just to show any duplicate countries but I don't know how to eliminate the duplicates from my table. I'm new to SQL and I've only learned the `IF EXISTS` function. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to handle a multiline IF ELSE (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717(v=sql.110).aspx)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblCountry WHERE strCountry = @strCountry)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblCountry (strCountry) VALUES (@strCountry)
END;
```

In general though, I'd be concerned about a procedure that uses the data to drive the possible values in a lookup list, especially something like countries that should probably be pre-defined up front.  You'd hate for them to enter free-form duplicates that are really the same country with a slightly different spelling.